# Check if a certain driver probed successfully from an unrelated second driver - Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

Is it possible to check whether a driver, say "A", has probed successfully from within another driver, say "B", using only the name of driver A?

I want to call a function within driver B but only if driver A has probed successfully. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean "probed" successfully? In driver A's load function, it probes for its H/W? Or, do you mean "loaded" succesfully? The results of the probe are generally internal to the given driver (in its private data). Unless the driver provides a specific exported call for this, it's generally very difficult. Presumably, you can just call A's function. If the probe failed, it should return some error. So, _why_ do you want to do this? Do you control [the source to] both drivers? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: For hotplug devices, you could check the probe is okay. But, then call the function. But, between the check and the call, the H/W is unplugged (i.e. probe is "failing" because no H/W). So, you'd still have to check the call return value. I've written many device drivers and I'm not seeing the utility or a solid implementation of this.

Comment: probed successfully == loaded successfully.
I don't want to call the function, as it won't return false or true depending on whether driver A loaded successfully or not. So I can't use that option (I would not be asking the question here otherwise...).
Anyways, I am not asking whether people see the usefulness of the ask, just asking if they know of a way to do it...
Thanks

Comment: ELF supports _weak_ symbols. I don't know if the kernel supports these for `.ko` but you might define one for a given function. Or, following the call tree for `/proc/kallsyms`, there are some functions for symbol lookup. But, how is B using (e.g.) Afunc? I've done a "two part" driver before but it's been 10+ years. IIRC, If it's an extern in B, B won't load if A isn't already loaded--so no problem. Or, the funcA address is NULL? You can always do what `/proc/modules` does and look for the module for driver A.

Comment: Thanks! My driver is out of tree, and when trying to use filp_open to open /proc/modules, it throws me an undefined modpost error. Any suggestion on how to make this easy and acceptable to read /proc/modules from an out of tree kernel, just to check if the driver A is in there?

Comment: From `fs/open.c`, the comment for `filp_open`: _This is the helper to open a file from kernelspace if you really have to.  But in generally you should not do this, so please move along, nothing to see here.._ I can't remember if I tried `filp_open` for `/proc/*` but, IIRC, it doesn't work too well. Parsing `/proc` files is _easy_ for a userspace app but [more] difficult for a driver/module. Better to have a [perl/python] script that does all the reading/parsing of `/proc/whatever` and have _it_ do `modprobe` if it determines things are "safe". The right tool for the right job ...

Comment: Maybe you should post your module source code [and `Makefile`] in code blocks here. And, the commands you are using along with exact error messages. If you post those things, people [here] can download them, build them, and try them. It's still not clear to me what the original issue is. IIRC, you can build a dependency into your module so that `modprobe` can load `A` [first] when you do `modprobe B`. You may want to look at `depmod`, possibly with `-b`. Since you have to be(come) `root`, you can copy your `.ko` into (e.g.) `/lib/modules/xxx/extramodules`